# Python pip --index-url Not Limiting Repository Search

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, pypi

I'm trying to instruct pip to install packages using only a local repository (on a different  server in my internal network). The requirement is that remote repositories (like pypi) should never be consulted, even if the local repository does not have a match.

First Attempt:

```
$ pip install --index-url=http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/ paramiko --verbose
```

However, when I run the command above, it's clear that other repositories are still being consulted:

```
....
Ignoring link http://www.amk.ca/files/python/pycrypto-1.9a5.tar.gz
(from http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/pycrypto/),
version 1.9a5 doesn't match >=2.1,!=2.4
```

The only workaround I've found thus far is to pip download (without installing), and then easy_install the tarball.

Example:

```
$ sudo pip install --no-install --download /tmp/ --index-url=http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/ paramiko
$ sudo easy_install --allow-hosts=<local.repo.host> --index-url http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/ /tmp/paramiko-1.9.0.tar.gz
```

Which results in the remote repositories being blocked:

```
Link to http://www.amk.ca/files/python/pycrypto-1.9a5.tar.gz
***BLOCKED*** by --allow-hosts
```

I also tried setting ~/.pydistutils.cfg to:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/
allow_hosts = <local.repo.host>
```

And ~/.pip/pip.conf to:

```
[global]
index-url = http://<local.repo.host>/packages/pypi/data/web/simple/
```

as suggested by the "What to do when PyPI goes down" blog, but that does not prevent attempts to remote repositories either.

Is there a more straightforward way of accomplishing this? I'd prefer to not use easy_install given that pip is heavily favored (for a lot of reasons). Will this approach even work in all situations?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Fixed by upgrading pip.